# .setNumberFormat is not working in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

I have the following code in my Google Apps Script which gets data from my Google Spreadsheet, and row 15 (the last row) returns an error saying `TypeError: percent1.setNumberFormats is not a function (line 15, file "Code")`. What should I change to fix this?

What I want to do is, I want to display `dod1` in a percentage format like `0.00%`

```
function notifySlack(message) {

  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx';
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var allSheets = spreadSheet.getSheets();
  var theSheet = allSheets[1];
  var lastRow = theSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = theSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheetData = theSheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  
  var ymd = Utilities.formatDate(sheetData[44][0], 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  
  var data1 = sheetData[44][1];
  var percent1 = sheetData[44][1] / sheetData[43][1];
  var dod1 = percent1.setNumberFormat('0.00%');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when the values of `sheetData[44][1]` and `sheetData[43][1]` are the numbers, `percent1` of `var percent1 = sheetData[44][1] / sheetData[43][1];` is the number. When those are the string, `percent1` is `NaN`.
- And, `setNumberFormat` is the method of Class Class Range. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String))

By these situation, your script occurs the error. This is the reason of your issue. Unfortunately, from your script, I couldn't understand about the detail of your goal. So in this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns for your goal I guessed.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the value of `percent1` of `var percent1 = sheetData[44][1] / sheetData[43][1];` is modified to `0.00%`. In this case, the value of `dod1` becomes a string.

From:

```
var dod1 = percent1.setNumberFormat('0.00%');
```

To:

```
var dod1 = Utilities.formatString("%1.2f%", percent1 * 100);
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the method for using `setNumberFormat` is explained. When you want to modify the number format of the cell "A1" in the active sheet, you can use the following script. In this case, the value of the cell "A1" can be used as the number.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
range.setNumberFormat('0.00%');
```

#### References:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String))
- [formatString(template, args)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)

Comment: Tanaike - One more quick thing if I may, if I wanted Pattern1 to be used in a way with some formatting like "[Green]+#,##0;[Red]-#,##0", is there a way to do this?
I would like to make the format rich based on positive/negative numbers if possible.

Comment: @oki_oki Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as new question including more information using the sample values? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Tanaike - here is my new question. Would be helpful if you could take a quick look.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282966/utilities-formatstring-with-positive-negative-numbers