# Utilities.formatString with positive/negative numbers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to display my numeric string data with a rich format, applying a different color when the number is positive or negative.

My current code is:

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx';
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var allSheets = spreadSheet.getSheets();
var theSheet = allSheets[1];
var lastRow = theSheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = theSheet.getLastColumn();
var sheetData = theSheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);

var rawData = sheetData[1][1];
var calcData = sheetData[1][1] / sheetData[0][1];
var formattedData = Utilities.formatString("%+1.2f%", calcData * 100);
```

and the result for `formattedData` looks something like:

> +12.1%

And I'm thinking it would be better if this was shown in different colors, green letters if positive and red letters if negative.

Related case: [.setNumberFormat is not working in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280041/setnumberformat-is-not-working-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `formattedData` is the string value. When you want to change the font color, in this case, the value is required to be set to the cell. So in this case, I would like to propose the method for changing the font color in the cell.

If `theSheet` in your script is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var calcData = -0.1234;
theSheet
  .getRange("A1")
  .setValue(calcData)
  .setNumberFormat('+0.00%;-0.00%;0.00')
  .setFontColor(calcData > 0 ? "green" : "red");
```

- In this sample script, `-12.34%` is put to the cell "A1" and the font color is red.
- When `var calcData = 0.1234;` is used, `+12.34%` is put to the cell "A1" and the font color is green.
- When you want to use `Utilities.formatString`, the sample script is as follows.

  ```
    var calcData = -0.1234;
    var formattedData = Utilities.formatString("%+1.2f%", calcData * 100);
    theSheet
      .getRange("A1")
      .setValue(formattedData)
      .setFontColor(calcData > 0 ? "green" : "red");
  ```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [setFontColor(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontcolorcolor)
- [formatString(template, args)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)